# ssh messages polluting my console

Tags: ssh, logging

While connected to my ubuntu 16.04 server via ssh, my console is polluted with messages like this:

```
root@backup ~ # 2017 May  2 15:05:05 backup fatal: Unable to negotiate with XXX port 45700: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
2017 May  2 15:05:07 backup fatal: Unable to negotiate with XXX port 45991: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
2017 May  2 15:05:07 backup fatal: Unable to negotiate with XXX port 45981: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
...
```

XXX is a foreign ip (not mine and not the ip of my server). So there seems be a dictionary attack on the ssh service, which is very common. How can i send these messages to a logfile instead of getting them on the console?

**EDIT**

sshd_conf

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#Note that match is effective "until either another Match line or the end of the file."
#(the indentation isn't significant)
Match User rsnapshot
PasswordAuthentication no
```

**EDIT**

```
root@backup ~ # sysctl -a | grep kernel.printk
kernel.printk = 4   4   1   7
kernel.printk_delay = 0
kernel.printk_devkmsg = ratelimit
kernel.printk_ratelimit = 5
kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst = 10
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
```

Comment: Please post sshd.conf

Comment: added sshd_conf

Comment: Please post output of `sysctl -a | grep kernel.printk`.

Comment: added output of: sysctl -a | grep kernel.printk

Comment: Maybe some things in `/etc/rc.local` or your clients `.bashrc` doing some stuff?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the syslog config?

Comment: @mzhaase
i'm using external logging via loggly. syslog-ng is configured to send the logs via tcp, see https://github.com/ernoaapa/ansible-loggly/blob/master/templates/22-default.conf.j2

Comment: what do you mean by "console"? the actual `vty1`? or xterm? or what?